# Can't select date in workflow using PWA

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, project-server, pwa

I have a date field in my PWA Projects. I would like to use that date in a workflow to calculate another stage's due date.  My thinking is to calculate a new date from the Project Data/Existing date field.

I am using Sharepoint Designer 2013, and when I try to calculate the new date, I add the calculate Action, and choose a value, select Project Data, and choose the Existing Date, but then OK grays out and I cannot use that value as part of the calculation.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to use set project field, but it would not let me select the variable. I deleted the line, saved the workflow exited sharepoint and when I reopened it, I was able to then do the same thing and it worked. So never mind! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Do Calculate action** is not used with `date type`

It's used with only numbers to can perform `+, - ,/ ,*`

[image]

Meanwhile, to be able to add days to a date field you should use **Add Time to Date** action as shown below.

[image]

**Note:** in **Add Time to Date** action specify the period that you need to add to your date and specify your `Project Date` field as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer!   Do you know how I set that value back into a Project Data date field?   I would assume I use set the Project value to the Workflow variable that I created in your answer, but it won't let me select the Variable....

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you :) , Regarding your new question, Please let me access to my test environment to check it and feedback you  :)

Comment: Do you try to use Set Project Field? once you have select this action yu have two value, one value to select your project field and the second to select the generated variable  I tried on my side and working properly!